# Any suggestions for what Node.js modules I should use for user log ins?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, authentication

I am building a website with the MEAN (mongodb, express, angular, node js) stack. I want users to be able to create an account on my site as well as integrate with facebook/twitter accounts. The main two options I am considering right now are [Passport](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport) and [Express-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt).

I have been able to find examples of integrating Passport into node/express, but no examples of how to handle things on the front end with angular. Is this hard to do?

My main concern about express-jwt is that I have not found examples of using that with facebook log ins while there is [passport-facebook](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook) for passport. Thanks for your help.

Comment: [npm's stats](https://www.npmjs.org/) and dev activity on github are worth considering when choosing a package. I'd personally go with passport.

Answer (score 0):

By Far the best for authentication is Passport. See the link

> https://github.com/DaftMonk/angular-passport If this could prove of worth to you. Also go through the article 
>   http://speakingaword.blogspot.in/2013/08/authentication-in-angularjs-nodejs-and.html can also be productive. Hope this is what you were asking.